# compare between 2 Same-length byteArrays

Tags: c#, performance, arrays

there's two methods i was looking at @stackOverFlow , i guess there might be even more of them
somewhere else , my qusetion is what is the best performance wise

and second question , i have this code that simply takes a couple of `byte[]`

```
     bool ArraysEqual(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
     {
         if (a1 == a2)
             return true;
          if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
             return false;
          if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
             return false;
          for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
         {
             if (a1[i] != a2[i])
                 return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
```

and i couldn't implement this one , not kowing the workaroud iguess i've used the wrong syntax
so if i have a helper method to read a byet[] file

```
    public byte[] readByteArr(string FilePath)
    {
       return File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

    } 

i could make it simply via 



void CompareIt(){

byte[] src = readByteArr(S.bar);
byte[] dest = readByteArr(D.bar);
if(ArraysEqual(src, dest))
DoSomthing
}
```

how do i make `CompareIt()`, with sets of parameters requierd in this Second code i allso try to implement, just to check which performs beeter

```
    bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
    {
     if (ReferenceEquals(a1,a2))
         return true;
      if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
         return false;
      if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
         return false;
      EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
     for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
     {
         if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i]))
            return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

what is the right syntax to implement this last one, and if there's a quicker way to compare two

```
 byte[]
```

knowing **they're the same length** .
and what do you think about this ?

**ReEditing:**
[image]

the first is unsafe code .

second is first code i wrote (`bool ArraysEqual()`)

and third is

```
myArray.SequenceEqual(otherArray);
```

**Now Take A good look at this** 
please Do allow me to announce, the winner is :

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);

static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
{
    // Validate buffers are the same length.     
    // This also ensures that the count does not exceed the length of either buffer.
    return b1.Length == b2.Length && memcmp(b1, b2, b1.Length) == 0;
}
```

@Chaos . **Can u please post the implemetation of Your Random with my Pinvoke** ?

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some parallel versions. They really shine when you have large equal arrays.

Comment: thanks A Lot i hope to "meet" you behind those codes again @stackOverFlow , please folow me or somthing ... as i am yet  familiar with stack overflows features i couldn't find how to contact you .

Comment: seems to me that my "case" is allways the worse (:
native is by far with my captured images(toByte[])  comparison project allmost 100% of time

Comment: i reEdite This last coment:
allmost 100% of time? <reEdit>adding: a minute after writing this coment i thought regarding your: "depends on the data type " , should we filter `arrayName.Length` to see what we're dealing with first then draw the right wepon ? then we are not in just shooting in the dark , any thoughts ? did i pick the wrong parameter or not the most important one or not the only one that counts ?

Comment: very sorry for my english... didn't have the time to recheck spelling .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use .NET > 3.0:

```
myArray.SequenceEqual(otherArray);
```

see [MSDN - Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

if you want to use a custom "EqualityComparer" you can use [MSDN - Enumerable.SequenceEqual with IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb342073%28v=vs.100%29)

;-)

Comment: i think about... he's talking about byte-array-comparison, about "file-content reading" and about GENERIC-array-comparison...

imho, the "SequenceEqual"-Method will perform best on EVERY case using 1. native code and 2. the right equalitycomparer....

Comment: It's short code, so I commonly use it. But it is pretty much the slowest method to compare two arrays.

Comment: @TheHe thanks for your time , going to compare premitive vs `SequenceEqual` i am still looking for the fatest way so if somone's reading this (i hope) i will come back here to chek and edit my post with benchmarks

Comment: @CodesInChaos you're of the opinion that this method is *really* a lot slower then doing it manually? quite not sure... if you do that with "myArray.AsEnumerable()" it *can* be slow, but imho it **should** be intelligent enough, that arrays can be compared faster than O(n^2) ;-)
we should benchmark that to see, what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Err both this and the OP's code are O(n). But this probably has 4 interface calls per byte, whereas the OP has at worst two array bounds checks and a simple comparison+branch. I'm >90% sure that this is *much slower* than the OP's first code. And even the OP's code is probably much slower than an unsafe implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I'm gonna have to agree that this will be slower. I've taken a look at the implementation in ILSpy and there are about 3 method calls and 3 property accesses when testing each element. That's without digging further into the `IEnumerator` and `IEqualityComparer` implementations.

Comment: tested via stop wach 1 try then whileLoop for 100 times to get a chance to see if there's a difference between primitive codeblock #1 and your SequenceEqual on 100K rounds less then 10% faster but premeteve won

Answer (score 1):

- Best: Data is random
- Worst: Data is equal
- Average: The average of the best case and worst case

A real test would include cases where the data is nearly equal among other things but the average we see here gives us a pretty good idea how these things will perform if your data could be almost anything. The best algorithm is really a matter of what kind of data you expect. Notice that the single threaded safe method is the fastest in the best case but the slowest in the worst case.

[image: Performance]

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);

    static bool AreEqualNative(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        return memcmp(a, b, a.Length) == 0;
    }

    static bool AreEqualSafe(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
    {
        if (a1 == a2)
            return true;
        if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
            return false;
        if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a1[i] != a2[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static bool AreEqualSafeParallel(byte[] a1, byte[] a2, int start, int length)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (a1[i] != a2[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static bool AreEqualSafeParallel(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        bool b1 = false;
        bool b2 = false;
        bool b3 = false;
        bool b4 = false;
        int quar = a.Length / 4;
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => b1 = AreEqualSafeParallel(a, b, 0, quar),
            () => b2 = AreEqualSafeParallel(a, b, quar, quar),
            () => b3 = AreEqualSafeParallel(a, b, quar * 2, quar),
            () => b4 = AreEqualSafeParallel(a, b, quar * 3, a.Length)
        );
        return b1 && b2 && b3 && b4;
    }

    static unsafe bool AreEqualUnsafe(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        int len = a.Length / 8;
        if (len > 0)
        {
            fixed (byte* ap = &a[0])
            fixed (byte* bp = &b[0])
            {
                long* apl = (long*)ap;
                long* bpl = (long*)bp;

                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    if (apl[i] != bpl[i])
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        int rem = a.Length % 8;
        if (rem > 0)
        {
            for (int i = a.Length - rem; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static unsafe bool AreEqualUnsafeParallel(byte[] a, byte[] b, int start, int length)
    {
        int len = length / 8;
        if (len > 0)
        {
            fixed (byte* ap = &a[0])
            fixed (byte* bp = &b[0])
            {
                long* apl = (long*)ap;
                long* bpl = (long*)bp;

                for (int i = start; i < len; i++)
                {
                    if (apl[i] != bpl[i])
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        int rem = length % 8;
        if (rem > 0)
        {
            for (int i = length - rem; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static unsafe bool AreEqualUnsafeParallel(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        bool b1 = false;
        bool b2 = false;
        bool b3 = false;
        bool b4 = false;
        int quar = a.Length / 4;
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => b1 = AreEqualUnsafeParallel(a, b, 0, quar),
            () => b2 = AreEqualUnsafeParallel(a, b, quar, quar),
            () => b3 = AreEqualUnsafeParallel(a, b, quar * 2, quar),
            () => b4 = AreEqualUnsafeParallel(a, b, quar * 3, a.Length)
        );
        return b1 && b2 && b3 && b4;
    }

    static readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
    static void SpeedTest(string name, int length, int iterations, Func<byte[], byte[], bool> func)
    {
        var a = new byte[length];
        var b = new byte[length];

        _rnd.NextBytes(a);
        _rnd.NextBytes(b);

        var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            func(a, b);
        }
        sw1.Stop();

        var c = new byte[length];
        var d = new byte[length];

        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            func(c, d);
        }
        sw2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(name + ":");
        Console.WriteLine("  Best: " + sw1.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("  Worst: " + sw2.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("  Average: " + TimeSpan.FromTicks((sw1.Elapsed.Ticks + sw2.Elapsed.Ticks) / 2));
    }

    static void Test(bool shouldBeEqual, byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (shouldBeEqual != AreEqualSafe(a, b))
            throw new Exception();
        if (shouldBeEqual != AreEqualSafeParallel(a, b))
            throw new Exception();
        if (shouldBeEqual != AreEqualUnsafe(a, b))
            throw new Exception();
        if (shouldBeEqual != AreEqualUnsafeParallel(a, b))
            throw new Exception();
        if (shouldBeEqual != AreEqualNative(a, b))
            throw new Exception();
    }

    static void VerifyCorrectness()
    {
        Test(true,
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });

        Test(true,
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });

        Test(false,
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 },
        new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12 });
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VerifyCorrectness();

        var length = 1000000;
        var iterations = 10000;

        Console.WriteLine("Length:");
        Console.WriteLine("  " + length.ToString("N"));
        Console.WriteLine("Iterations:");
        Console.WriteLine("  " + iterations.ToString("N"));

        SpeedTest("Safe", length, iterations, AreEqualSafe);
        SpeedTest("SafeParallel", length, iterations, AreEqualSafeParallel);
        SpeedTest("Unsafe", length, iterations, AreEqualUnsafe);
        SpeedTest("UnsafeParallel", length, iterations, AreEqualUnsafeParallel);
        SpeedTest("Native", length, iterations, AreEqualNative);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using larger elements will make it even faster, but makes the handling of the last few bytes a bit annoying.

Comment: @CodesInChaos , i get the following Error Error 1 Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe

Comment: @LoneXcoder You need to enable unsafe code in the project options.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I'm honestly surprised that I could not get this to be at least on par with the safe version for a random distribution. If you look at the IL there are simply a lot more instructions being generated. Without the unsafe cast to long it would be slower on the even distribution as well.

Comment: @LoneXcoder - Just check check the Build pane of your project properties. You'll see a check box labeled "Allow unsafe code".

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Actually it seems the 64-bit build is a bit closer to what I expected.

Comment: @ChaosPandion what about this ha ??
        static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
Have A Look Redtinig Big Time , i hope i am not missing a hidden entrance to the sewer with using pinvok dll import , have a look posting the whole method too

Comment: @LoneXcoder - On my system the call to memcmp is just a bit faster than my unsafe version when using non-random data. Pretty nice actually.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I just posted it right now .. look at the second image
as if i don't have a pc or calculator in front of me can u please do a favor calculate 3157/169 ???

Comment: now if u want to accelerate anything , is it with testing on x86 vs x64 (cause i heard not allways x64 wins) , and  will multithreding speed it ? or it is allredy taken care of by system somehow to load it on all 4 cores

Comment: its 18.6 times than Unsafe !!(i ment it by Pinvoke of course)

Comment: @LoneXcoder - Something like this might see improvement by using multiple cores but it would really only make sense on very large data sets.

Comment: thanks A Lot i hope to "meet" you behind those codes again @stackOverFlow , please folow me or somthing ... as i am yet familiar with stack overflows features i couldn't find how to contact you .